# Retrieve records using Hibernate Projections and the AliasToBeanTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to retrieve some records from a collection base on this condition. I need all the properties from trades and operations:

select trade from Trade as trade inner join trade.operations as operation with to_char(operation.datetime, 'yyyyMMdd') = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyyMMdd') order by operation.datetime

If I use this query with hibernate, I will get all the operations once I iterate the trades.

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue using Hibernate Projections / the AliasToBeanTransformer, but I can't find the solution.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's you end goal? Load trades and their operations in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

if you are retrieving all values from a configured bean the you don't need to use `AliasToBeanTransformers`  since hibernate knows which class the properties need to go to.

you need to use projections to load contents of Trade class..